# ASP.NET repeater control: how to pass parameter from frontend to repeater ItemCommand event

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I need to pass parameter from frontend to backend using repeater control
My frontend code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
            onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" 
            onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
....
<asp:Button ID="btn_Reply" runat="server" Text="Reply" CommandName="Reply" CommandArgument='<%Eval("id").ToString() %>'/>
....
</asp:Repeater>
```

Repeater1_ItemCommand event at backend:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Reply":
            ReplyThread(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
            break;
        case "Edit":
            EditThread(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
            break;
        case "Delete":
            DeleteThread(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
            break;
    }
}
```

When click reply button, Why it says e.CommandArgument is not in a correct format., the value in debug model is just a bunch of string: <%Eval("id").ToString() %>, not it's id value.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead of your other eval :

```
<%# Eval("id").ToString() %>
```

Comment: What can I say. I just made a stupid mistake which I thought some other problems. Appreciate it!